# AngularJS binding + chrome re-draw bug: text is not refreshed

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

(i can't reproduce in jsfiddle and i can't reveal my company's website.)

It happens in few situations, and only in chrome (works fine on firefox)

**The problem:**

Binded texts are not displayed until the page is **re-drawn**.

**Details:**

I know that it's not a bug in my code, because I can see that the same variable binding  works elsewhere on the page, and the change IS visible there.

e.g.

```
<div something-unknown>
  1. {{ my.var }}    <!--  won't redraw -->
</div>
...
test case:
  2. {{ my.var }}     <!-- works ok -->
```

more importantly,

When I cause the page to redraw (not a full reload!), then the displayed binding is "fixed" and the correct values are shown, i.e.

- by selecting text with the mouse,
- or by resizing the window,
- or scrolling,

I suspect that this bug is related to values that return from an ajax call.

i've seen more of this bug when i had ng-cloak directives, but i removed all of them.

Question is:
is this a known bug, or is it something to do with specific code?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was with `ng-show`, so my answer reflects that.

In some cases, Chrome won't execute DOM manipulations (Chromium too) on `fixed` or `static` positioned elements. It's not an issue with redraw, but with reflow, since looping a CSS animation does not prevent it. It doesn't seem to happen when the heap is small.

Chrome dutifully removes the `.ng-hide` class from the markup, and the element *is* in fact visible in the DOM, but its `height` and `width` are `0px` no matter what you do with your CSS or javascript. In computed styles in Dev Tools, you'll find nonsense like this:

> `min-height: 100px;`
>   `height: 0px`

Here are two ways that I was able to prevent it:

1. CSS: Use `relative` positioning for the element that contains the directive or interpolated value. It generally won't work if you simply wrap your element in a container that has your desired `position` property. This imposes heavy layout limitations.
2. JS/CSS: Set the `position` property of the container element or directive to `absolute` every time Angular retrieves the bound value. This forces Chrome to reflow the element. It doesn't seem to work with anything other than `absolute`. I have no idea why.

   ```js
   $scope.getValue = function () {

     // ...

     $('.selector').css({position: 'absolute'}); // Assumes jQuery

     return $scope.someValue;
   }());
   ```

To use the second option within Angular, you'll want to interpolate/bind a function rather than a value (*e.g.,* `{{ getSomeValue() }}`). Within that function, you can invoke the code above.

I will look into filing a bug with the Chromium team. Because this is weird. And irritating.